# Word for the feeling of thrill when doing something for the first time

Tags: vocabulary

I want a funky word for the feeling of thrill when doing something for the first time. The word should contain 'first'

Comment: More often encountered in the negative, there's [This ain't my first rodeo](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=not+my+first+rodeo), where [(one's) first rodeo](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/(one's)-first-rodeo) is defined as *one's first time doing something.*

Comment: Butterflies in stomach.

Comment: Can you give a phrase with the word you want left blank please?

Comment: 'Anticipation' is often used in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is "First show jitters" or "Pre show jitters" or even "first day jitters".

If you don't fancy the use of "first", then maybe "[ecstatic](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=ecstatic)"?

"The way he kissed her neck, she felt spiralling out of control, ecstatic."

"With a final click, his bionic leg just finished the automatic instalation, his brain recognized a difference, ecstatic, he got up for the first time without his cane."

Answer (score 0):

Consider **first-night nerves**

> *3(nerves) Feelings of nervousness: his first-night nerves soon disappeared*
>
> I don't normally get stage fright or nerves before a performance but today I'm like a child on Christmas Eve.
>
> First-night nerves aside, what she fears most is being left alone… without her Tim.
>
> He was visibly, rather endearingly, anxious, shaking with nerves at some points; she kept erupting into fits of maniacal chuckles at some secret joke.

From   http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nerve